# Scrapy: How to get the number of pages?

Tags: python, html, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to get the number of pages on this [site](https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Acupuncture&entityCode=PS004&where=CA&pageNum=2&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA), but nothing works.

```
response.css('._2uKgC p::text').getall()
```

html:

```html
<nav class="_2uKgC" aria-label="Page navigation" data-qa-target="pagination">
<p class="">Page 2 of 209</p>
<ul>...</ul></nav>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This element is not present in html you can check "view page source" to check what HTML you are getting instead of inspect element.

Comment: I looked, but did not understand how it works. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `sessionId` and `requestId` from HTML code and next request this URL:

```
f"https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/usearch?where=CA&sessionId={sessionId}&requestId={requestId}&sort.provider=bestmatch&source=init&what=Acupuncture&category=provider&cid&debug=false&debugParams=false&isPsr=false&isFsr=false&isFirstRequest=true&pageNum=1&userLocalTime=23%3A55"
```

After to you parse JSON response you'll find `["search"]["totalPages"]` (and `["search"]["totalCount"]`) values.